# mousemove not working on object element

Tags: javascript, html, object, svg

Is there a way to make the `mousemove` event handler work over an HTML <object> tag? I have HTML like this:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="myfile.svg"></object>
<img src="myfile.svg"/>
```

and some JavaScript/jQuery like this:

```
$("img, object").on("mousemove", function() {
  $("body").css("background-color","#f0f");
});
$("img, object").on("mouseleave", function() {
  $("body").css("background-color","transparent");
})
```

But the `mousemove` is only working over the `img` tag. Applying `pointer-events: all` to `object` or `object *` didn't seem to help.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2rvy44sw/).

```js
$("img, object").on("mousemove", function() {
  $("body").css("background-color","#f0f");
});

$("img, object").on("mouseleave", function() {
  $("body").css("background-color","transparent");
})
```

```css
img, object {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Mouse over the images to change the background color.  It doesn't seem to work for the object tag.

<h2>SVG as &lt;object&gt;</h2>

<object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ea/Converted_to_SVG.svg"></object>

<h2>SVG as &lt;img&gt;</h2>

<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ea/Converted_to_SVG.svg"/>
```

Comment: what happens if you select an element in the svg xml and apply mousemove event handler to that? or add an attribute onmousemove="console.log('foo')" ?

Comment: You can't. Inspect the SVG and you will see that the `<object>` tag actually create a new document to render the SVG into. Behaving a bit like iframe to some extend.

Comment: Have you tried using `onmouseenter`? or are there specific things you wish to do when the mouse moves?

Comment: @Tschallacka Part of it is getting e.pageX and e.pageY. I may just have to end up using your wrapper approach for that.

Comment: @GillesC I tried to access the document via contentDocument, but wasn't having luck getting that to work. If you have better JS skillz than me, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Now that I think about it, getting contentDocument probably didn't work since jsfiddle and wikimedia would have cross-domain issues.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using `onmouseenter`? or are there specific things you wish to do when the mouse moves?

if so, I suggest you wrap the object into a inlined div, and add the listener to the div, and set pointer events to none on the object.

See the example below:

```js
$("img, .objectwrap").on("mousemove", function() {
  $("body").css("background-color","#f0f");
});

$("img, .objectwrap").on("mouseleave", function() {
  $("body").css("background-color","transparent");
})
```

```css
img, object {
  width: 100px;
}
object {
  pointer-events:none;
  }
.objectwrap {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Mouse over the images to change the background color.  It doesn't seem to work for the object tag.

<h2>SVG as &lt;object&gt;</h2>

<div class="objectwrap">
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ea/Converted_to_SVG.svg"></object>
</div>
<h2>SVG as &lt;img&gt;</h2>

<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ea/Converted_to_SVG.svg"/>
```

Comment: This should totally be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

The `object` tag represents something that is not considered part of the DOM. This is done so that the user can interact with it directly. It was originally designed for external applications like Flash.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object